# Proportion data: - beta regression or logit transformed OLS regression?

Tags: r, regression, logit, beta-distribution

I have proportion data (percentage viewership of TV programs) that i'd like to model as a function of various demographics (age, sex etc.) and time (year). After surveying options for appropriate multiple regression models, I'm debating between the following two strategies:

1) fit a beta regression model after dividing the percentage data by 100 and adjusting the range slightly so that values of zero and one do not occur.

2) fit an OLS model after logit transforming the percentage data (again, divided by 100 and adjusted slightly) so that the dependent variable is mapped to the Real line.

One key consideration is that i'd like to make the results as intuitive as possible to a non-statistical audience. So, interpretations such as "for a one unit change in X we get a percent change in Y", or something like that, would be most welcome.

Can anyone outline pros and cons of these two approaches in this regard?

It seems to me that using beta regression with a logit link, and then calculating odds ratios may lead to nice "percent change" explanations. The coefs from the OLS model would also be on the ln(odds) scale, so I assume I could also do the same for that model. My data are too large to share, but I ran both models in R and there are only minor differences in the coefs.

Comment: The fudge of moving away from 0 and 100 is difficult to defend here. At a minimum you would need to do some sensitivity analysis to see the effects of the constants you used. Also, tell us more about 0 and 100. It seems likely that there are spikes in your data if 0 and 100 occur at all, which rather undermines the idea of a beta distribution. Some people have worked with zero-inflated betas.

Comment: @Nick Cox. Unfortunately, I don't know how to add a plot here. The distribution contains six 0s and zero 1s (out of 10K+ observations). There is a spike at about 3%, and about 2/3 observations fall between 0% to 7%. The max is about 18%. Why would this undermine the idea of a beta distribution? I thought the beta dist. were ideal for exactly this situation (providing there's no 0 or 1 inflation)?

Comment: Agreed that the spikes sound minor, but now you need to address your fudging. Using a generalised linear model with logit link shouldn't require fudging. I don't think you are going to get an approach intuitive to a non-statistical audience either way.

Comment: @Nick Cox. Beta distributions can only be fit to data in the interval (0, 1), so there has to some "fudging" - in this case six 0 observations have a small constant added. Since I don't have the numerator/denominator data for the proportions, I can't use another type of generalized linear model. And anyway, the data are not the result of Bernoulli trials. Moving from percentages to proportions is trivial I think. Odds ratios seem easy to explain, since an OR of say 1.81 represents an 81% increase in Y for a one unit increase in X.

Comment: As I said, my suggestion was a GLM with logit link, not a beta distribution fit. That does _not_ depend on numerator and denominator being known separately, nor on Bernoulli trials. Nor are observed 0s and 1s a problem. See http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=st0147 for a review with details of how to do it in Stata. (Excellent if your audience is happy with odds ratios.)

Comment: Naturally I know you are using R. But my point is that you can do what I say in principle. How to do it in R exactly I don't know.

Comment: @Nick Cox. The link you sent about the glogit command is for a fractional logistic regression model (to my eyes) and does require numerator and denominator of the proportion - it mentions this explicitly in the text. You can fit this in R too, but need the numerator and denominator. The beta regression is a flavor of GLM and it also uses a logit link, but doesn't require knowledge of the numerator and denominator of the proportion.

Comment: Not so. The paper I linked mentions Stata's `glogit` command at the outset, but goes on to talk about using `glm`. What I've mentioned does work with fractions, does not depend on knowing numerator and denominator, and I have used it. If the canned R version does not support that, some custom programming is required. It's your choice whether to use beta regression, but as your approach appears to require fudging away from the limits, it appears less satisfactory to me.

Comment: @Nick Cox. Ok, thanks a lot for your input - i'll take a closer look. Does this model have a specific name? (since glogit, beta regression etc. are all `glm`s). It seems like a zero-inflated fractional logistic regression from what they describe (logit link and binomial family).

Comment: No zero inflation, no one inflation; just that observed zeros and ones are not fatal. Fractional logit would be one name. The reference to binomial in software calls is just a trick but the point of the literature is that the trick is a fair one. The model goes back to Wedderburn at least.